# iPhone 6 causes Bose Mie2i to skip tracks

Tags: iphone, health.app, headphones

I purchased Bose MiE2i in ear headphones today and as I am walking the track skips forward every 5-10 seconds or so. If I stand still there is no issue.  I performed a hard reset and verified I was running iOS 8.2 with no change. I duplicated at a table moving only the phone and not the cable to rule out a short (it still skipped).  I tried my wifes iPhone 6 and had the same results.  I used a regular iPod shuffle and it works fine.  I am thinking it has something to so with the step monitor in the health app but there is no way to switch it off to verify.  Any ideas?  Jim

Comment: Have to eliminate the headphones as the source of the interruption - try it over just the internal speakers, see if it does the same. If not, I'd seek out Bose for advice.

Comment: It does it over the internal speaker.  Headphones are fine.  Now to assess why it's doing it over the internal speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off shake to shuffle in Settings > Music